# Read data from different directories using Firebase for Android

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

```
/users:
 - user1
       - name: user1name
       - /contacts
              - user2
              - user3
                .....
 - user2
       - name: user2name
       ....
```

This is my current firebase database. When user1 is logged in I check which contacts he has and get their UIDs. Now that I have their UIDs I'm trying to read the names of his contacts. How can I get the names for each of his contacts? Do I have to read the entire /users directory or can I use a query that retrieves only the data that I want. (In this case: the name of user2 and user3)

Comment: You'd do a nested read. So retrieve `/users/$uid/contacts`, then loop over the keys in there and for each key load `/users/$key`.

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I wanted to know. If you post this comment as an answer, I will mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd do a nested read. So retrieve `/users/$uid/contacts`, then loop over the keys in there and for each key load `/users/$key`.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that you already have the user selected, you can go about it in two ways:

1) Use `.child(String user);` in your database reference.

2) You may have declared a URL for your database. Add `+ "/" + String user;` to your URL.

You can further use these ways to parse through contacts of that user.

Finally, to retrieve contacts, you have to loop through.

Here is an example code:

```
  mRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot msgSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    mDataset.add(msgSnapshot.getKey());
                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        }
```

This snippet fetches data and adds it to your adapter (which can be used to populate list view, grid view etc)

Comment: thanks for your response. I know how to get the different properties like a user's name. i was trying to ask how I can retrieve the name for every user that is a contact of user1. i hope you understand what i'm trying to say. It's not about one name. It's about several names. Do I retrieve the data in a loop or is there another way?

Comment: If there are multiple entries (which is obvious for contact list), you have to make a loop.